# Sqlite alias column give an error

Tags: mysql, sqlite

this is my table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `calls` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

and there are data on it its

[image]

now i use this query for get type  data with same day

```
SELECT user.name_first calls.date as days, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(type) FROM   calls WHERE DAY(date) = DAY(days) ) FROM calls JOIN user ON user.user_id =  calls.user_id WHERE calls.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM calls GROUP BY  DAY(calls.date))
```

as we see i  do this `calls.date as days`  and try to get type for this data by

```
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(type) FROM   calls WHERE DAY(date) = DAY(days) )
```

its work on mysql result in mysql

[image]

but when i try it on sqlite its say

> no such column: days (code 1): , while compiling

i read sqlite support alias

Comment: It suport aliasses, but you can not use it in where statements

Comment: @Jens so how can i get data like mysql result :/

Comment: use the column directly without the alias

Comment: @Jens i need current  date not column date its will give wrong result i try it

Comment: There is no `day()` function in SQLite. Show the actual query you're using.

Comment: @CL. yes i solve the alias day now have problem on `DAY` which function equation to `DAY` in sqlite ?